# Sidekiq not accepting Rake task arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, sidekiq

When I run my rake task:

```
namespace :foo do
  task :bar => :environment do
    MyWorker.perform_async(some_id)
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
{"retry"=>3, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"MyWorker", "args"=>[3], "jid"=>"05737ccbac2c88443e3014c4", "enqueued_at"=>1392842821.15404, "error_message"=>"wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)", "error_class"=>"ArgumentError", "failed_at"=>2014-02-19 20:47:01 UTC, "retry_count"=>0}
```

Now, the weird part is that if I just run the part `MyWorker.perform_async(some_id)` on my rails console, it works perfectly

MyWorker.perform is like:

```
def perform some_id
  MyModel.new(some_id).sync
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your perform method is taking in the some_id argument, then I is most likely the `MyModel`. What does `MyModel`'s initialize method look like?

It could also be a bug with rails: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/601

Comment: It's like:
    def initialize(provider, authorization = {username: ENV['USERNAME'], password: ENV['PASSWORD']})
      self.provider = provider
      self.authorization = authorization
    end

Comment: What does the sync method look like? Is it working on any associations of MyModel?

Comment: It scans and saves products. I tested it and works perfectly.

I think the point is that when I call `MyWorker.new.perform(some_id)` it works, but `MyWorker.perform_async(some_id)` won't

Comment: My main thoughts are that there are some rails bugs with associations that pop up with Sidekiq.